# add or push a 10th index number to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach, splice

I was working on a chart where i need my data to be sliced into small object based for better visibility. My array that i have is

```
   {
      "size":[
        {
          "timestamp":"1641329889000",
          "size":12345,
          "fees":123456,
          "cost":168
        },
        {
          "timestamp":"1641387032",
          "size":456789,
          "fees":4567891,
          "cost":249
        },
        {
          "timestamp":"1641435786",
          "size":98765,
          "fees":987654,
          "cost":987
        },
        {
          "timestamp":"1641435786",
          "size":98765,
          "fees":987654,
          "cost":987
        },
        {
          "timestamp":"1641435786",
          "size":98765,
          "fees":987654,
          "cost":987
        }
      ]
    }
```

in which i want the array to be in this form

```
{
  "size":{
    "timestamp": ["1641329889000","1641387032","1641435786"],
    "size": [12345,456789,98765],
    "fees": [123456,4567891,987654],
    "cost": [168,249,987]
  }
}
```

i can achieve this using foreach and push like this

```
 result.forEach(element => {
     this.state.timestamp.push(element.timestamp);
     this.state.size.push(element.size);
  });
```

But i want this array to have the items only from the 10,20,30,40th index alone
I want not all the value. the values should be chosen only in the basis of x+10
Could anyone help me on this

Comment: You can use the `for` loop with the increment of 10.

Comment: and what should happen for repeated timestamps?

Comment: If you have an array and you want to reduce it then you have to `.reduce()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `forEach` why not just use a `for` loop, and on the condition use the modulus `%` operator with 10? Like `if (i % 10 == 0)` inside of the for loop, or just increment i by 10 like `i+=10`.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a `for` loop and a step for incrementing the index.

```
const
    step = 10,
    keys = ["timestamp", "size", "fees", "cost"],
    result = Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k => [k, []]));

for (let i = 0; i < size.lenght; i += step) {
    keys.forEach(key => result[key].push(size[i][key]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `forEach` is a waste of resources.
You can use `for` instead:

```
for(let i=0;i<result.length;i+10){
   this.state.timestamp.push(result[i].timestamp);
   this.state.size.push(result[i].size);
}
```

For setting the state you should use `setState` not just push to it.

```
    let tmp = {
      ...this.state
    }
    for(let i=0;i<result.length;i+10){
       tmp.size.timestamp.push(result[i].timestamp);
       tmp.size.push(result[i].size);
    }
    this.setState(tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @cybercoder, you probably don't want to change the `state` variable within the `forEach`, as that will cause `render` to be called excessively.

You could simply use a counter and only push elements when the index is divisible by 10:

```js
 let i = 0;
 let {timestamp, size} = this.state;

 result.forEach(element => {
     if (i % 10 === 0) {
         timestamp.push(element.timestamp);
         size.push(element.size);
     }
     i++;
  });

  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    timestamp,
    size
  });
```

If you do not want to include the very first (index 0) element:

```js
 let i = 0;
 let {timestamp, size} = this.state;

 result.forEach(element => {
     // Exclude very first element
     if (i % 10 === 0 && i !== 0) {
         timestamp.push(element.timestamp);
         size.push(element.size);
     }
     i++;
  });

  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    timestamp,
    size
  });
```

Comment: update react state variables in a loop? Won't makes too much renders?

Comment: Good catch. If you use a temp variable you can update the state variable after iterating through the results.